# Is there a framework that does what Spring Roo did with respect to forward engineering from a model defined in their model definition language?

Tags: spring, data-modeling, forward-engineer

Spring Roo had a feature that I would like to find -- It allowed you to define entities, with relationships and cardinalities and created a JPA Service repository layer and DDL for the database. Is this feature available in another framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there's [JHipster](https://www.jhipster.tech/). You can model them with [JDL](https://www.jhipster.tech/jdl/)

> The JDL is a JHipster-specific domain language where you can describe all your applications, deployments, entities and their relationships in a single file (or more than one) with a user-friendly syntax.